# How to use Oracle advanced to notify on XML changes

Tags: xml, oracle, advanced-queuing

We have an Oracle 12c AQ with a UDT payload containing an XMLType attribute.  Can we create a notifier that fires when the XMLType attribute matches some criteria?

I have not seen any examples of this online.

edit=>
Only getting notified about new messages where the xml part of the payload matches some criteria. Something like:

```
DECLARE subscriber sys.aq$_agent; 
begin 
    subscriber := sys.aq$_agent('SUBSCRIBER_1', null, NULL);
    DBMS_AQADM.ADD_SUBSCRIBER(Queue_name => 'MYUSER.MY_LOVELY_Q'
        , Subscriber => subscriber
        , Rule => 'tab.user_data.myXMLAttr <matches some criteria>');
end;
```

This subscriber will only get notified when the XML part of the payload matches the criteria.
<=End Edit

Answer (score 1):

You can use pl sql callback mechanism.

First create procedure.

```
 CREATE or replace PROCEDURE cbprocedure(
                     context  RAW,
                     reginfo  SYS.AQ$_REG_INFO,
                     descr    SYS.AQ$_DESCRIPTOR,
                     payload  varchar2,
                     payloadl NUMBER
                     ) is   
   BEGIN     
     write_log('Resived message with id='||descr.msg_id);
    /* 1).Dequge message using descr.msg_id with broser mode
       2). Check attributes in xml  
       3). Do something 
    */
  END;
```

For UDT(ADT) and xmltype queues `payload` is varcahr2.

`payloadl` - length of payload.

`payload` and `payloadl` for persistent queue is always `null` and `0`

`reginfo` - some info about registration

`descr` -  here we have more information about messages. `descr.msg_id` is pk in queue table. And we can use it to query table or dequeue indicate message.

Next you have to register the procedure. [AQ$_REG_INFO Type](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/t_aq.htm#i997071)

```
  begin
  DBMS_AQ.REGISTER (
          SYS.AQ$_REG_INFO_LIST(
             SYS.AQ$_REG_INFO(
                'XML_QUEUE',
                DBMS_AQ.NAMESPACE_AQ,
                'plsql://CBPROCEDURE?PR=1',
                HEXTORAW('FF')
                )
             ),
          1
          );
   END;
```

Here 
`select * from USER_SUBSCR_REGISTRATIONS;` list of registered subscribed.

`select * from V$SUBSCR_REGISTRATION_STATS;` diagnostic information for callback/notification.

To unregister use DBMS_AQ.UNREGISTER with the same paramters.

Now if new msg will be enqueued. Oracla calls procedure "cbprocedure".

Comment: thanks for all the effort to create this example for me.  I'm looking for something that is kind of the next step.  Only getting notified about new messages where the xml part of the payload matches some criteria.  Something like:
DECLARE
   subscriber sys.aq$_agent;
begin
subscriber := sys.aq$_agent('SUBSCRIBER_1', null, NULL);
DBMS_AQADM.ADD_SUBSCRIBER(Queue_name => 'MYUSER.MY_LOVELY_Q', Subscriber => subscriber, Rule => 'tab.user_data.myXMLAttr <matches some criteria>');
end;
This subscriber will only get notified when the XML part of the payload matches the criteria.

Comment: Understand and you can do this. 
`ADD_SUBSCRIBER( ... rule=>
'tab.user_data.myXMLAttr.extract(''/x_paTH TO ELEMENT'').getStringVal()=''sOMETHING''')'`